# How can I keep my text within the confines of a frame

Tags: swift, swiftui, draggesture

I have a draggable text and I have a red rectangle . I am trying to have that draggable text within that red rectangle and to only allow it to be dragged inside that rectangle . I have this code so far and it does everything that I need except the restricting the draggable text part to be inside the red rectangle, any suggestions on how I can confine the draggable text to only be inside the red rectangle ?

```
struct DraginContainerView: View {
    @State var viewState = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            
            
                Text("My Text")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .offset(x: viewState.width, y: viewState.height)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                viewState = value.translation
                            }.onEnded { value in
                                self.viewState = value.translation
                            }
                    )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `VStack` to a `ZStack` so the text is on top of your `Rectangle()`

We have to get the width and height of the text. This is not easy, but we we can achieve this by applying a `GeometryReader` to a clear text background.

The last thing is to check if our translation from the `DragGesture` is in your predefined width and height of the `Rectangle()`.

```
struct DraginContainerView: View {
    @State var viewState = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    @State var textProxy = CGSize.zero
    let width: CGFloat = 200
    let height: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
            
            Text("My Text")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .offset(x: viewState.dx, y: viewState.dy)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            if value.translation.width < (width/2 - textProxy.width/2) && value.translation.width + (width/2 - textProxy.width/2) > 0  {
                                viewState.dx = value.translation.width
                            }
                            if value.translation.height < (height/2 - textProxy.height/2) && value.translation.height + (height/2 - textProxy.height/2) > 0 {
                                viewState.dy = value.translation.height
                            }
                        }.onEnded { value in
                            self.viewState = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
                        }
                )
                .background {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear {
                                textProxy = proxy.size
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate its position relative to the rectangle's frame and then adjust its position based on the bounds of the rectangle. Here's an updated code that should do what you want

```
struct DraginContainerView: View {
@State var viewState = CGSize.zero
let rectangleSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(width: rectangleSize.width, height: rectangleSize.height)
            .overlay(
                Text("My Text")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .offset(x: viewState.width, y: viewState.height)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                var newPosition = CGSize(width: viewState.width + value.translation.width, height: viewState.height + value.translation.height)
                                newPosition.width = min(max(newPosition.width, 0), rectangleSize.width)
                                newPosition.height = min(max(newPosition.height, 0), rectangleSize.height)
                                self.viewState = newPosition
                            }
                    )
            )
    }
}
```

}